# what is the best way to split string data that is delimited in php

Tags: php

Looking for php help, best practice. What is a good way to break these lines? I was looking into explode or is a regex better? and then maybe display them into a table? thanks for your input.

input file:

```
PRE:abc:KEY1:null:KEY2:/myproject/data/dat_abc_2010120810.gz1
PRE:def:KEY1:sdsu:KEY2:mail_abc.dat.2010120810.gz1
```

expected output or web page for display:

```
PRE  KEY1 KEY2
===  ==== ======================================
abc  null /myproject/data/dat_abc_2010120810.gz1
def  sdsu mail_abc.dat.2010120810.gz1
```

Comment: Go with `explode` -- don't use regex when it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a file like that I would do it in two steps if I were you...

**1st step**

Use [file()](http://php.net/file) to get an array representing the file.

**2nd step**

Now you can use **explode()** to get all the different columns and output them.

Quick example:

```
<?php
$output = "";

$file = file("data.txt");
foreach ($file as $line)
{
    $cols = explode (":", $line);
    $output .= "{$cols[0]} {$cols[1]}";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

[explode](http://php.net/explode) will work just fine:

```
$fp = fopen('myfile.txt', 'r');
while ($line = fgets($fp))
   $parts = explode(':', $line);
   $array = array();
   for ($i=0; $i<count($parts); $i+=2) {
      $array[$parts[$i]] = isset($parts[$i+1]) ? $parts[$i+1] : 'null';
   }
   print_r($array);
}
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [PRE] => abc
    [KEY1] => null
    [KEY2] => /myproject/data/dat_abc_2010120810.gz1
)
Array
(
    [PRE] => def
    [KEY1] => sdsu
    [KEY2] => mail_abc.dat.2010120810.gz1
)
```